# How do I convert a directory (including multiple subdirectories) of .flac files to .mp3s using Bash?

Tags: bash, loops, mp3, subdirectory, flac

I have a root directory with subdirectories, all containing .flac files. I would like to convert all the .flac files to .mp3 files, and delete the .flac files afterwards, so they are not taking up excess storage space.

I have the following command to convert the .flac files and remove them, which works well:

```
for f in *.flac; do flac -cd "$f" | lame -b 320 - "${f%.*}".mp3; done && rm -Rfv ./*.flac
```

Can you please help with a command loops that over the root directory and subdirectories and performs the conversion and deletion afterwards? Thank you.

Comment: Replacing `*.flac` with `**/*.flac` might be enough (requires `shopt -s globstar`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `globstar` option and use the pattern `**/*.flac` to match all `*.flac` files in the current directory and in its subdirectories. Also, you may want to change the logic to remove converted flac files.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.flac; do
    flac -cd "$f" | lame -b 320 - "${f%.*}".mp3 # && rm "$f"
done
```

Drop the `#` before `&& rm "$f"` after making sure it will work

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked brilliantly. 
Can I please ask, 1) what does the "shopt -s globstar" do? and 2) is there any way to add a user input question so that you are prompted to submit the absolute path of the root directory you want to perform the action on? I realise these questions expand the scope of my original one, so no problem if you don't want to answer them. 
Thanks again.

Comment: @ktb 1) `shopt -s globstar` sets the `globstar` option. After setting this option, two adjacent `*`s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories, in a filename expansion context. If followed by a `/`, two adjacent `*`s will match only directories and subdirectories. 2) Something like that: `read -p 'Enter base directory: ' basedir; cd "$basedir" || exit`. Here, `basedir` is just an ordinary variable. You can use any (valid) name, instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name \*.flac) ; do
  flac -cd "$f" | lame -b 320 - "${f%.*}".mp3 && rm "$f"
  done
```

it will replace each *.flac within your current directory tree into a *.mp3 and remove the original

Comment: Don't do that. That won't work if filenames contain spaces. `find` is just as bad as `ls` *in this context*. Consider reading [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: in case there spaces in the names (bad idea, actually) you could put your flac ... sequence into a shell script (let's call it x.sh) and do the following: find . -type f -name \*.flac exec x.sh {} \;

Comment: Which will need extra work and increase complexity of the script, while globs are working simply and safely even for filenames containing newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -type f -iname '*.flac' | while read flac_file; do mp3_file=$(sed 's/\.flac/.mp3/gi' <<< ${flac_file}); flac -cd "${flac_file}" | lame -b 320 - "${mp3_file}"; [ -s "${mp3_file}" ] && rm -f "${flac_file}"; done
```